# React Higher Order Component - call function in the wrapped component from the wrapper component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

Assuming I am using the right pattern, I would like to be able to call `someFunc()` - which is inside `<Home/>` - from inside `<Wrapper/>`. See below:

```
var Home = React.createClass({
  someFunc() {
    console.log('How can I call this from <Wrapper/>?')
  },
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
  }
})

var Wrapper = (Home) => {
  return React.createClass({
    render() {
      return <Home {...this.props}/>
    }
  })
}

var HomeWrapped = Wrapper(Home)

ReactDOM.render(<HomeWrapped/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

**updated with solution**: https://codepen.io/oldgithub/pen/qPOZEj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ref` for that:

```
var Wrapper = (Home) => {
  return React.createClass({
    render() {
      return (
          <div>
              <button onClick={() => {this.home.someFunc()}} />
              <Home
                  {...this.props}
                  ref={(c) => this.home = c;}
              />
          </div>
      );
    }
  })
}
```